# MySQL comparing rows and getting changes

Tags: mysql

Kind of lost on anything more than selects and joins and need help with this.  I have a table that maintains attributes of products that are created.  There are currently 110k rows in that table.  I'm looking for a way to query that data and return data related to changes in the attributes of each product.

```
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| attrib_id | prod_id | height | weight | length |
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|         1 |     120 |     20 |      3 |      5 |
|         2 |     101 |      5 |     10 |     20 |
|         3 |     101 |      5 |     10 |     20 |
|         4 |     101 |      5 |     10 |     20 |
|         5 |     120 |     20 |      3 |      5 |
|         6 |     101 |      8 |     10 |     20 |
|         7 |     120 |     20 |      3 |      5 |
|         8 |     101 |      8 |     15 |     30 |
|         9 |     101 |     16 |     15 |     20 |
|        10 |     120 |     20 |     10 |      3 |
+-----------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I would like to see something like this as an output when ever a product attributes change:

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| attrib_id | prod_id | orig_height | new_height | chg_height | orig_weight | new_weight | chg_weight | orig_length | new_length | chg_length |
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|         6 |     101 |           5 |          8 |          3 |          10 |            |            |          20 |            |            |
|        10 |     120 |          20 |            |            |           3 |         10 |          7 |           5 |          3 |         -2 |
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: How do you store history about changes now?

Comment: Your example output is just that, an example, right? If I understand correctly, the real expected output from the example input should have 4 rows, with `attrib_id in (6, 8, 9, 10)`, is this correct?

Comment: chg_height= new_height - orig_height ??

Comment: McNets,  the change is just a new row in the table.  The history is the previous rows in the table.

Dario, the example is just an example.  I'd like to see the original, the new, and what the difference is for what was changed.

Comment: @Jockser - Shouldn't the new_height for 101 be 16? and new weight be 15?

Comment: And is there a date or any order? maybe attrib_id?  Please, add an @ in front of names, if not I don't receive any notification about your message

Comment: attrib_id also should be 9 for 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output is bit incorrect.

You want to find min and max attrib_id and then use aggregation to find the required values:

```
select attrib_id,
    prod_id,
    original_height,
    case when original_height = new_height then null else new_height end new_height,
    nullif(new_height - original_height, 0) chg_height,
    original_weight,
    case when original_weight = new_weight then null else new_weight end new_weight,
    nullif(new_weight - original_weight, 0) chg_weight,
    original_length,
    case when original_length = new_length then null else new_length end new_length,
    nullif(new_length - original_length, 0) chg_length
from (
    select t2.max_id attrib_id,
        t.prod_id,
        max(case when t.attrib_id = t2.min_id then t.height end) original_height,
        max(case when t.attrib_id = t2.max_id then t.height end) new_height,
        max(case when t.attrib_id = t2.min_id then t.weight end) original_weight,
        max(case when t.attrib_id = t2.max_id then t.weight end) new_weight,
        max(case when t.attrib_id = t2.min_id then t.length end) original_length,
        max(case when t.attrib_id = t2.max_id then t.length end) new_length
    from t
    join (
        select prod_id,
            min(attrib_id) min_id,
            max(attrib_id) max_id
        from t
        group by prod_id
        ) t2 on t.prod_id = t2.prod_id
        and t.attrib_id in (t2.min_id, t2.max_id)
    group by t.prod_id
    ) t;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/SYCVTS67637)

Comment: GurV that is REALLY close to what I'm looking for, only thing would be not to show products that haven't changed.

Comment: @Jockser How do you mean? Can you provide an example?

Comment: so if a product never had any changes to any of the attributes I wouldn't want it to show in the report.  in your Demo if you add a new row for a product that never changes it wouldn't show up in the query.  In this demo attribute_id 11 or 12 shouldn't show up in the query
  http://rextester.com/WEDVP28028

Comment: I ended up going with this solution @GurV.  Thank you all for helping I learned a lot.  I did add "where original_height != new_height
 or original_weight != new_weight
    or original_length != new_length" to the end of the query to remove those entries that have not ever changed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I will suggest a completely different approach. I thought about it reading the words “when ever a product attributes change” in your question. Other answers recompute all joins and aggregates every time, while your table `t` is essentially a history log which is bound to grow and grow and your query will be slower and slower. My approach is to create a table `report` and keep it in sync by means of a trigger. You have to start with two empty tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t (attrib_id INT, prod_id INT, height INT, weight INT, length INT);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS report;
CREATE TABLE report (
   attrib_id INT,  prod_id INT,  
   orig_height INT, new_height INT, chg_height INT,  
   orig_weight INT, new_weight INT, chg_weight INT,  
   orig_length INT, new_length INT, chg_length INT
);
```

and then, define the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trig AFTER INSERT ON t FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE old_prod_id, old_height, old_weight, old_length INT;
  SELECT prod_id, new_height, new_weight, new_length 
    INTO old_prod_id, old_height, old_weight, old_length 
    FROM report 
   WHERE prod_id = NEW.prod_id;
  IF ISNULL(old_prod_id) THEN
    INSERT INTO report(attrib_id, prod_id, orig_height, orig_weight, orig_length)
        VALUES (NEW.attrib_id, NEW.prod_id, NEW.height, NEW.weight, NEW.length);
  ELSEIF old_height != NEW.height OR old_weight != NEW.weight OR old_length != NEW.length 
        OR ISNULL(old_height) -- First change: I suppose checking one field is enough 
        THEN
    UPDATE report SET 
      attrib_id = NEW.attrib_id,
      new_height = NEW.height, chg_height = NEW.height - orig_height,
      new_weight = NEW.weight, chg_weight = NEW.weight - orig_weight,
      new_length = NEW.length, chg_length = NEW.length - orig_length
     WHERE prod_id = NEW.prod_id;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When you fill `t` with the values you’ve given us, you get:

```
> SELECT * FROM report;
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| attrib_id | prod_id | orig_height | new_height | chg_height | orig_weight | new_weight | chg_weight | orig_length | new_length | chg_length |
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|        10 |     120 |          20 |         20 |          0 |           3 |         10 |          7 |           5 |          3 |         -2 |
|         9 |     101 |           5 |         16 |         11 |          10 |         15 |          5 |          20 |         20 |          0 |
+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

and you have a much more flexible situation, where you can easily fine-tune your `SELECT ... FROM report` query as you like it.

Comment: I don't have access to create any new tables but this idea is really intriguing.  Might need to pursue this with the the DBA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what are you looking for but it tracks all changes:

```
select attrib_id, prod_id, 
       height as ori_height, nheight as new_height, (nheight - height) as chg_height,  
       weight as ori_weight, nweight as new_weight, (nweight - weight) as chg_weight,
       length as ori_length, nlength as new_length, (nlength - length) as chg_length
from (
        select attr1.attrib_id, attr1.prod_id, attr1.height, attr1.weight, attr1.length
                ,(select attr2.height from attr attr2 
                  where attr2.prod_id = attr1.prod_id and attr2.attrib_id > attr1.attrib_id limit 1) nheight
                ,(select attr2.weight from attr attr2 
                  where attr2.prod_id = attr1.prod_id and attr2.attrib_id > attr1.attrib_id limit 1) nweight
                ,(select attr2.length from attr attr2 
                  where attr2.prod_id = attr1.prod_id and attr2.attrib_id > attr1.attrib_id limit 1) nlength
        from attr attr1
        order by attr1.prod_id, attr1.attrib_id
     ) calc
;
```

It returns all changes, row by row:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| attrib_id | prod_id | ori_height | new_height | chg_height | ori_weight | new_weight | chg_weight | ori_length | new_length | chg_length |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2         | 101     | 5          | 5          | 0          | 10         | 10         | 0          | 20         | 20         | 0          |
| 3         | 101     | 5          | 5          | 0          | 10         | 10         | 0          | 20         | 20         | 0          |
| 4         | 101     | 5          | 8          | 3          | 10         | 10         | 0          | 20         | 20         | 0          |
| 6         | 101     | 8          | 8          | 0          | 10         | 15         | 5          | 20         | 30         | 10         |
| 8         | 101     | 8          | 16         | 8          | 15         | 15         | 0          | 30         | 20         | -10        |
| 9         | 101     | 16         | NULL       | NULL       | 15         | NULL       | NULL       | 20         | NULL       | NULL       |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 1         | 120     | 20         | 20         | 0          | 3          | 3          | 0          | 5          | 5          | 0          |
| 5         | 120     | 20         | 20         | 0          | 3          | 3          | 0          | 5          | 5          | 0          |
| 7         | 120     | 20         | 20         | 0          | 3          | 10         | 7          | 5          | 3          | -2         |
| 10        | 120     | 20         | NULL       | NULL       | 10         | NULL       | NULL       | 3          | NULL       | NULL       |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```